# Transform column of array in multiples columns

Tags: arrays, pyspark

I have the dataframe below :

| created_at_dt | oid | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 | 600072e0a | [Val: 1200.0, Razao: 0.0, Score: 5, Insight: True, LM: True] |

I need to transform the steps column array into several columns, like the example below :

| created_at_dt | oid | Val | Razao | Score | Insight | LM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-10-01 | 600072e0a | 1200.0 | 0.0 | 5 | True | True |

How can I do this process? Can you help me ? I'm using pyspark.

I tried to use the split, pivot and explode functions but without success.

Comment: What is the datatype of `steps` column?

Comment: @notNull the column datatype is string, but it is inside another field which is an array

Below is the schema :

root
 |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at_dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- decision_steps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- steps: string (nullable = true)